# How to get the progress of a running build using TFS REST API?

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm monitoring builds on TFS & VSTS and would like to know how to get the overall progress (in percentage) of a running build or release.

Comment: What version TFS?  And are you using XAML builds?

Comment: Using Fiddler or the browser console and sniff the Rest calls of a running build

Comment: What does the following request return? "GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version={version}"

Comment: From here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds

Comment: The solution should support VSTS & TFS2015+, both XAML and vNext builds.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Rest API [Get build details](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#timeline) with timeline.

```
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/timeline?api-version={version}
```

Which will return build timeline and some more detail info including a **percentComplete** result. Note: this is task level based just like the build log in webportal, not the entire build.

***Sample response***

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "id": "bcddc27d-c891-4209-85d6-387e155439b0",
      "parentId": "045f4ce9-cb71-424f-84de-4ab19281dc70",
      "type": "Task",
      "name": "Build solution **\\*.sln",
      "startTime": "2015-07-16T19:53:20.853Z",
      "finishTime": "2015-07-16T19:53:28.567Z",
      "currentOperation": null,
      "percentComplete": 100,
      "state": "completed",
      "result": "succeeded",
      "resultCode": null,
      "changeId": 16,
      "lastModified": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "workerName": "Hosted Agent",
      "order": 2,
      "details": {
        "id": "ef959107-e566-4c28-8d9f-354d605dd400",
        "changeId": 6,
        "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/6ce954b1-ce1f-45d1-b94d-e6bf2464ba2c/_apis/build/builds/391/Timeline/ef959107-e566-4c28-8d9f-354d605dd400"
      },
      "errorCount": 0,
      "warningCount": 1,
      "url": null,
      "log": {
        "id": 2,
        "type": "Container",
        "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/6ce954b1-ce1f-45d1-b94d-e6bf2464ba2c/_apis/build/builds/391/logs/2"
      },
      "issues": [
        {
          "type": "warning",
          "category": "General",
          "message": "The MSBuild version parameter has been deprecated. Ignoring value: latest",
          "data": {
            "type": "warning"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "b5bb4de7-a8ea-4c7d-8491-3f745bba7d1b",
      "parentId": "045f4ce9-cb71-424f-84de-4ab19281dc70",
      "type": "Task",
      "name": "Get sources",
      "startTime": "2015-07-16T19:53:07.057Z",
      "finishTime": "2015-07-16T19:53:19.493Z",
      "currentOperation": null,
      "percentComplete": 100,
      "state": "completed",
      "result": "succeeded",
      "resultCode": null,
      "changeId": 13,
      "lastModified": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "workerName": "Hosted Agent",
      "order": 1,
      "details": null,
      "errorCount": 0,
      "warningCount": 0,
      "url": null,
      "log": {
        "id": 1,
        "type": "Container",
        "url": "https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/6ce954b1-ce1f-45d1-b94d-e6bf2464ba2c/_apis/build/builds/391/logs/1"
      }
    },
```

[image]

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to get or calculate estimation of the overall progress, not just a single task within the build.

Comment: @AlonAmsalem Unfortunately, this is not  available with using Rest API for now. You could add a uservoice  in this link https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services , TFS PM will kindly review your suggestion.